# Show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{e^n - (\sqrt{e})^n} = e$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have two sequences and I need to find their limits
$a_n = \sqrt[n]{e^n - (\sqrt{e})^n}$
$b_n = \sqrt[n]{e^n - (1 + \frac{1}{2n})^{n^2}}$
So I know that the limit is $e$, but I don't know how to show it

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: Mor generally, show $\sqrt[n]{a^n-b^n}\to a$ if $a>b>0.$

Comment: I tired Squeeze Theorem, but I have problem with lower value

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{e^n - (\sqrt{e})^n}= \sqrt[n]{e^n(1-e^{-n/2})}=e\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{1}{e^{n/2}}}$$

Comment: thanks, what do you think about $b_n$?

Comment: @A.Rokinsky: you can use the same idea